# Why ViewPager doesn't swiping inside RelativeLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, android-viewpager

**After changing Linear Layout to Relative layout swipe change doesn't work.**

Whole xml code here.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/singleSlider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/slider_height"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/singleScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        ...

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What can be a problem?

It doesn't work also with Frame Layout.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

The `NestedScrollView` is now above (z-axis) the `ViewPager`, so the `ViewPager` doesn't receive the touch events. 
Add

```
android:layout_below="@+id/singleSlider"
```

to your `NestedScrollView`.

Comment: Yes that right, now swipe working, but content inside NestedScrollView became not visible

Comment: @TigranBabajanyan If the ViewPager is now visible (you can check by giving it a background color), then that should be a different problem, probably with your data or adapter. I would recommend you post a new question for that with the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your View-pager and NestedScrollView are **overlapping** earlier you are using **Linear Layout**. So it goes one by one but now in Relative Layout it is overlapping.
Use **layout_below** attribute

Comment: Yes it works, but content inside NesteedScrollView became invisible, have you any idea?

Comment: I think Your view pager taking much space than nested scroll view ..You can do one thing divide whole height space in two equal section and give equal height to both i.e nested and viewpager.

Answer (score 0):

right now your nested scroll view and your view pager are just 2 seperate things that over lap each other not sure if you want your view pager inside your nested scroll view or if you want the nested scroll inside of your view pager so i will show view inside the nested scroll

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/singleScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/singleSlider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/slider_height"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

then when you call your scrollview

you can also set

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

on the nested scroll view to Defines whether the scrollview should stretch its content to fill the viewport

if this is not what you wanted could you maybe show a mock up or something showing how you want it to function and I will edit my answer accordingly

Comment: I don't want to put viewpager inside ScrollView because I don't want to scroll it with other elementes in scroll view